# Proving $\mathcal{F}\left(\frac{d^n}{dx^n} f(x)\right)=(ik)^n\mathcal{F}(f(x))$.

Tags: proof-writing, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

I am trying to prove the $n^{th}$ transform of the Fourier transform: 
$$\mathcal{F}\left(\frac{d^n}{dx^n} f(x)\right)=(ik)^n\mathcal{F}(f(x)) \tag{1}.$$
I have solved the problem for the case $n=1$ by using integration by parts:
$$\mathcal{F}(f'(x))=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f'(x) e^{-ikx} \ dx=ik\mathcal{F}(f(x)).$$ I think that solving $(1)$ requires $n$ iterations of integration by parts, by i'm having trouble writing this formally. Some help would be really appreciated.

Comment: You'll need to assume that $f$ and is derivatives up to order $n-1$ vanish at $\pm\infty$. Or you'll need conditions that imply it.

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts Yep, I believe we are allowed to assume this. Given this assumption, do we prove by induction?

Comment: A proof by induction is the correct way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Using formal induction**

We want to show that $\mathcal{F}\{f^{(n)}(x)\} = (ik)^n \, \mathcal{F}\{f(x)\}.$

Basecase: For $n=0$ the identity is trivial.

Induction step: Assume that the identity is valid for some integer $n=p \geq 0$. Then,
$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{F}\{f^{(p+1)}(x)\} 
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f^{(p+1)}(x) \, e^{-ikx} \, dx \\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \left( \left[f^{(p)}(x) \, e^{-ikx}\right]_{-\infty}^{\infty}  - \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f^{(p)}(x) \, (-ik)e^{-ikx} \, dx \right) \\
&= ik \, \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f^{(p)}(x) \, e^{-ikx} \, dx \\
&= ik \, \mathcal{F}\{f^{(p)}(x)\} \\
&= ik \, \left((ik)^p \, \mathcal{F}\{f(x)\} \right) \\
&= (ik)^{p+1} \, \mathcal{F}\{f(x)\}, \\
\end{align}$$
i.e. it's also valid for $n=p+1.$

Conclusion: By the induction principle, the identity is valid for all integer $n \geq 0.$

Comment: Should there be a condition that $f^{(p)}(x)\rightarrow 0$ as $|x|\rightarrow\infty$ (to remove the square bracket)?

Comment: Yes, there should.