# Prouve that $\mathcal{F}\{\frac{dx(t)}{dt}\} = 2i\pi f \mathcal{F}\{x(t)\}$

Tags: integration, complex-numbers, fourier-transform, complex-integration

I wanted to prouve that : $$\mathcal{F}\{\frac{dx(t)}{dt}\} =  2i\pi f \mathcal{F}\{x(t)\}$$
I started by the applying the definition of Fourier Transform and I integrated by parts:

$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{dx(t)}{dt} e^{-2i\pi ft} dt$ = $\Big [x(t)e^{-2i\pi ft} \Big]_{-\infty}^{+\infty}$ +  $ 2i\pi f\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}x(t) e^{-2i\pi ft} dt$

but I faced a problem in calculating $\Big [x(t)e^{-2i\pi ft} \Big]_{-\infty}^{+\infty}$ I couldn't calculate the limit of this complex number

can I get some help with explanation? much appreciated

Comment: $x,x'$ should be in $L^1$ as well as $x$ should be in $C^1$, thus, w.l.o.g. $x,x'\to 0$ when $|t|\to\infty$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proving $\mathcal{F}\left(\frac{d^n}{dx^n} f(x)\right)=(ik)^n\mathcal{F}(f(x))$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3205077/proving-mathcalf-left-fracdndxn-fx-right-ikn-mathcalffx)